# Correct location of header file for arduino sketches

Tags: arduino

I have NewSoftSerial.h and NewSoftSerial.cpp in the same folder as my sketch.

The sketch is thus.

```
#include <NewSoftSerial.h>

int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data
NewSoftSerial bluetooth(2, 3);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);   // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.flush();
  //enter command mode
  Serial.println("$$$");
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    //read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    //say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, BYTE);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that I get these errors?

> trainremotesketch.cpp:1:27: error:
>   NewSoftSerial.h: No such file or
>   directory trainremotesketch:3: error:
>   'NewSoftSerial' does not name a type

Comment: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that library files go in the libraries folder in the Arduino root folder. A library should be in a sub-folder named for the class, and should contain a c++ implementation and header file.

```
-Arduino
  |
  +--libraries  
       |
       +--NewSoftSerial
           |
           +--NewSoftSerial.cpp
           |
           +--NewSoftSerial.h
```

Answer (score 15):

A longer answer is that if you want to include a header file which isn't in the library path, you use double quotes, instead of angle brackets:

```
#include "NewSoftSerial.h"
```

Comment: This answer is actually shorter